# wicked_pdf + rails' asset pipeline + sass import in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline, production, wicked-pdf

I'm successfully using wicked_pdf with SASS in development. I'm including a single `.scss` file, which contains several `import` rules for other `.sass` and `.scss` files, via this helper:

```
def wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)
  sources.collect { |source|
    "<style type='text/css'>#{Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{source}.css").body}</style>"
  }.join("\n").gsub(/url\(['"](.+)['"]\)(.+)/,%[url("#{wicked_pdf_image_location("\\1")}")\\2]).html_safe
end
```

But switching to production the app still looks for the imported files which aren’t found.

I've added then a second manifest file to be pre–compiled in production.rb (`config.assets.precompile += %w(pdf.css)`) which contains a single `require` rule to pick up the mentioned `.scss` file. This file is compiled just fine but it seems that the helper doesn't pick up the right file in production and still looks to load the imported `.sass` files.

Has anyone experience how to solve this? The PDF creation requires absolute paths, which makes this task a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have wicked pdf working in development and production. This is the core of my wicked_pdf config:

I've updated WickedPdfHelper (loaded from initializers/wicked_pdf.rb) based on a wicked_pdf [pull request](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/pull/68/files) from github user antti

```
module WickedPdfHelper
  def wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)
    sources.collect { |source|
      "<style type='text/css'>#{Rails.application.assets.find_asset(source+".css")}</style>"
    }.join("\n").html_safe
  end

  def wicked_pdf_image_tag(img, options={})
    asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(img)
    image_tag "file://#{asset.pathname.to_s}", options
  end

  def wicked_pdf_javascript_src_tag(jsfile, options={})
    asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(jsfile)
    javascript_include_tag "file://#{asset.pathname.to_s}", options
  end

  def wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag(*sources)
    sources.collect{ |source| "<script type='text/javascript'>#{Rails.application.assets.find_asset(source+".js")}</script>" }.join("\n").html_safe
  end
end
```

then in app/assets/stylesheets/pdf.css I require a few sass stylesheets:

```
/* ...
*= require ./_colors
*= require_directory ./pdf
*= require_self
*/
```

(remember that if you're modifying initializers or anything in config/, you'll need to re-start your rails app to pull in the changes)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a article on this at: http://anlek.com/2011/09/wicked_pdf-working-in-rails-3-1/

It's very similar to Philip's solution with a few modifications.

Comment: Cached version of broken link: http://web.archive.org/web/20160728085119/http://anlek.com/2011/09/wicked_pdf-working-in-rails-3-1/